# Get all fields influenced by horse as point array

Tags: java, arrays, chess

I just can't figure this thing out. I'm making a chess game and I need to get figures influences...

I started with a horse and got quite stuck, even after drawing it on a paper. I want that as an array:

```
class Horse extends Figure {
    public int[][] getRadius() {
        //Allocate a max possible count of fields
        int [][] return = new int[8][2];
        //Now what?
        ???
    }
}
```

This is what I made for myself on a paper, repainted in Ms-paint, in hope it will help somebody else since it left me helpless.
[image]
Horse is sitting in the square and I think what I've drawn are all his possible moves. Sounds like a combenation of `{1,-1,2,-2}` with 2 members and no repeat, doesn't it? But how to do this programatically? (the list in the array must be **relative** to horses actual position!)
Thanks for any hint. If there is an article about other figures too, it would save me a lot of time!

<sub>If the image gives you silly ideas, please keep them for yourself, *thanks.*</sub>

Comment: Please use "Knight" or I just can't take this seriously.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.  Are these red points supposed to be the output of calling getRadius()?  Why are you using `int [][]`?  Wouldn't a `List` of `Points` be better?  Why would you call this `getRadius()`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Or go full silly and use "horsey"

Comment: It makes more sense to start the co-ordinates from 0,0 on a corner and use only positive co-ordinates. You can use array with more ease (arrays don't have negative indices).

Comment: You don't really need to find a more compact formula if you've discovered an enumeration of 8 (x,y) offsets that represent all possible moves.

Comment: The restriction isn't "no repeats" as that would permit `1 -1` as a valid combo. It's "no repeating absolute values" e.g. `|1| |-1|` shouldn't be permitted.

Comment: `(1,-1)` is sure not a valid move... I use zero center, because later on, I'm gonna apply all the vectors on *horseys* position to get actual points he can reach. Please, see the difference between *`vector`* and *`point`*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to get from `getRadius()` is every permutation of `(x,y)` with x, y ∈ {-2, -1, 1, 2} and |x| ≠ |y|.

```
int[][] ret = new int[8][2];
int[] set = {-2, -1, 1, 2};
int i = 0;
for(int x : set)
    for(int y : set)
        if(Math.abs(x) != Math.abs(y)){
            ret[i][0] = x;
            ret[i][1] = y;
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: I don't play chess, so I can't help you with the other figures, but I guess you just need to adapt the set and the condition in the second for-loop... And the length of the array `return`